# How to speed up load times for a huge tile grid of JLabels

Tags: java, instance, loading, jlabel, imageicon

I am attempting to create a sky-view RPG game, but the initial load times have become a bit of an issue. I am fairly new to programming and Java, so I don't know much about how Java loads things into memory or anything. 
So the issue is that when I initially run my program, it can take a very long time for all of my JLabels(set up in my grid) to appear. I am hoping to make a map that is very large, consisting of hundreds of thousands of tiles in total. After doing some math and tests, it turns out that 30 seconds of loading would result in merely about 6,724 tiles. This is only a bit over 8 screens worth of map, which is very small, since my character is a little smaller than 50x50 pixels. So for a map of a size from which I may be satisfied with would take over 6 minutes to load, upon every run. That is insane. And my map creator loads even more slowly.

Each tile is 50x50 pixels. Every tile is set up to have multiple layers of JLabels. For example, the first is for just a JLabel that the other labels will be added to, then the second is for Terrain(like Grass), and the third is for Interactive elements such as doors, so that the door may appear on top of the grass.

All of my Tile objects are created and inserted into a 2-dimensional Tile array. Every Tile instance has:

2 JLabels.

Icons added to at least, and usually only, the first JLabel. Every time a tile requests an icon, it gets it from the MapTiles class.

5 String arrays

7 booleans

4 ints

4 Layer instances in a Layer array of that size

Each Tile instance also implements MouseListener

Each Layer instance has:

1 JLabel with no icon, unless it is Grass. (75% of Layer instances aren't Grass)

4 booleans

1 int

1 String

The MapTiles class will create an ImageIcon for the thing, such as "Grass", if it hasn't already. If it has already created an ImageIcon for it, then it simply returns that ImageIcon. From reading about improving loading times, I was led that this may help speed things up, rather than creating a new ImageIcon for each Tile.

Here, I will provide the beginnings for each of my 3 main classes involved in creating/loading the grid. By beginnings, I mean only the constructor and the creating of the objects. There are a few other methods in each class, but not very many, and none used during the initial loading.

Tile class:

```
package Tiles;
import Datas.*;
import Images.*;
import MapCreation.*;
import UniversalVariables.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Tile implements MouseListener{
    public Layer[] layers = new Layer[4];
    //MAKE SURE THAT THE FOLLOWING INTEGERS MATCH THE ARRAY IN MAPDATA
    int terrain = 0;
    int interactive = 1;
    int destroyable = 2;
    int obstruction = 3;

    public JLabel image = new JLabel();
    JLabel mouseDetector = new JLabel();
    boolean hasBarrier = false;
    boolean hasModifiedBarrier = false;
    boolean isInteractive = false;

    boolean leftClickPressed = false;
    boolean rightClickPressed = false;
    boolean scrollClickPressed = false;
    String[] layerTypes = MapData.uni.tileLayerTypes;
    String[] terrainTypes = MapData.uni.terrainTypes;
    String[] interactiveTypes = MapData.uni.interactiveTypes;
    String[] destroyableTypes = MapData.uni.destroyableTypes;
    String[] obstructionTypes = MapData.uni.obstructionTypes;
    int tileSize = MapData.uni.tilePixelSize;
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    boolean mapCreatorOpen = UVars.uni.mapCreatorRunning;

    public Tile(int rowNum, int colNum){
        row = rowNum;
        col = colNum;
    setLayer("Terrain", "Grass");
    for(int c = 1; c < layers.length; c++){ //Sets all layers except terrain to have new layerName
        layers[c].layerName = MapData.uni.tileLayerTypes[c] + "NLT";
    }
    mouseDetector.addMouseListener(this);
    image.add(mouseDetector);
    mouseDetector.setBounds(0, 0, tileSize, tileSize);
    //image.setComponentZOrder(mouseDetector, 0);
    for(int c = 0; c < layers.length; c++){
        image.setComponentZOrder(layers[c].image, c);
    }
    image.setComponentZOrder(mouseDetector, 0);
}
```

}

Layer class:

```
package Tiles;
import Datas.*;
import Images.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Layer{
    public JLabel image = new JLabel();
    int tileSize;
    public String layerName = "No Layer Name";
    boolean hasBarrier;
    boolean hasModifiedBarrier;
    boolean isInteractive;
    boolean affectsMovement;

    public Layer(Tile tile, String layerType){
        //For empty layers
        tile.add(image);
    }
    public Layer(Tile tile, String layerType, String name){
        if(layerType.equals("Terrain") && name.equals("No Layer Name")){
            name = "Grass";
        }
        layerName = name;
        tileSize = tile.tileSize;
        tile.add(image);
        image.setBounds(0, 0, tileSize, tileSize);
        image.setIcon(MapTiles.uni.getIcon(layerName));
        if(layerType.equals("Terrain")){
            Terrain terrain = new Terrain(layerName);
            terrain.exchangeValues(this, layerName);
        } else if(layerType.equals("Interactive")){
            Interactive interactive = new Interactive(layerName);
            interactive.exchangeValues(this, layerName);
        } else if(layerType.equals("Destroyable")){
            Destroyable destroyable = new Destroyable(layerName);
            destroyable.exchangeValues(this, layerName);
        } else if(layerType.equals("Obstruction")){
            Obstruction obstruction = new Obstruction(layerName);
            obstruction.exchangeValues(this, layerName);
        }
    }
}
```

MapTiles class:

```
package Images;
import Datas.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MapTiles{
    public static MapTiles uni;
    String tileLoc = "Tile Graphics\\" + String.valueOf(MapData.uni.tilePixelSize) + "PX\\";
    ArrayList<ImageIcon> icons = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
    ArrayList<String> iconList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public MapTiles(){
        uni = this;
    }
    public ImageIcon getIcon(String tileType){
        for(int c = 0; c < iconList.size(); c++){
            if(iconList.get(c).equals(tileType)){
                return icons.get(c);
            }
        }
        iconList.add(tileType);
        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(tileLoc + tileType + ".png");
        icons.add(newIcon);
        return newIcon;
    }
}
```

So, why does my grid take so long to load? It is all created in the default Java thread, but that's because currently, I don't have any menu or anything else to distract a user with before getting to the map. The map starts immediately. What appears is the frame is just a blank panel. Eventually, once it finally creates the tiles in the top left corner once it has gotten that far(where the user's view defaults), you can see it creating each and the user may even hover on one. (Hovering over it changes the icon set on it) Hovering over it runs very well. Only the load times is the issue. So first off, are there any better ideas you guys have for creating such a grid? Secondly, are there better ways you can think of for doing the things I am attempting to do? And finally, is there anything that I have done wrong that I should improve upon? The main question I guess that I am asking is... What is it that is making Java take so long to load  new Tile instance? By the way, I have a fairly high-end PC. It's not some piece of junk. For example, I can run most pre-2015 PC games on maximum graphical settings, and I have 16GB of RAM. I also have another question you guys may be able to answer. I read that using the GPU to load things rather than mainly loading them into RAM runs MUCH more quickly, but it uses 3D Java or something like that. Would I be able to use my GPU to load many of the tiles somehow and improve the load times that way?

Comment: Side note on code quality: you want to read about java coding style guides -  package names should not start with upper case; and typically you would use more than word there, too. Then: don't use a **string** to distinguish things; combined with such switch statements. At least, you should be using enums (and even then: you really want to avoid those switch statements. Use OO and polymorphism instead!) Regarding performance ... key thing would be to only load those things that should be visible for example.

Comment: I will check on that. But what I don't understand is how I would load only what should be visible... Because I am only creating the Tiles. Everything seems to run perfectly once they have all been loaded, it's just that loading them initially takes a long time. Wouldn't it be kind of weird to actually instantiate Tiles in order to create my map as I roam around? Because I'm imagining having AI in areas that aren't loaded, and they would be unable to exist if the Tiles aren't created. So only items and characters from parts of my map that I've been to would be able to exist, right?

Comment: What I mean is: besides the "how do I make the loading faster by itself"; you could also looking into prioritized loading. Like: there will be some area "visible" to the user. Try to fetch those things that go "into that visible" area first; everything else can be loaded later on, for example when the user starts scrolling.

Comment: One other hint: when you are really about creating a game that other people will be running on their machines ... then make sure to really understand your performance bottlenecks. It doesn't help if you get "good enough" for got user experience on your very personal high-end machine (unless you want to restrict your users to such high-end hardware).

Comment: Alright, thank you for the advice. I will try this and see what kind of impact I can create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like you're loading the same images multiple times from disk for tiles.  Only loading what you need, then sharing that same resource in memory could help.

Also you probably shouldn't try to hold your entire map in memory but instead load each section as needed.

I'd recommend you ditch Swing and use [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/) or an engine backed by LWJGL.  This will give you hardware accelerated rendering typically not available through Swing (unless passing certain runtime flags.)  If you're concerned about quality Minecraft uses LWJGL.  Its really the way to go if you're going to use Java for game development.

Specifically I recommend [LIBGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) as your LWJGL backed game framework.  I've used it extensively and its a great way to get your game on multiple OS *and* mobile devices.

Comment: Alright, I will definitely check that out. But you said it looks like I'm loading the same images and that I should share them. But my MapTiles class only loads a type of image once, and from then on it would simply return that image rather than re-creating an ImageIcon for that type. So what do you mean? How else could I share the resource in memory?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed your caching in 'getIcon', good job.  Not sure why your code runs slow then.  Try running a profiler on your code, see where most your CPU is going.

Comment: http://imgur.com/89FPwd9   - Here is a link to a screenshot of the profiler on NetBeans.  What do you think the issue is really from, from what you see?

Comment: Hint: maybe holding everything in memory is **exactly** what he should do. One can only decide this after doing some profiling and in-depth understanding on what is going on (versus what should be going on). Meaning: I would stay away from such generic proposals - as you could be right, or giving the exact wrong advise.

Comment: I have chosen your answer as being the accepted one because you mentioned only loading each section as needed. I have now made it where it does just that, and it seems to run well. The only issue is that I have to slow down the loading after the viewed section is shown so that the program can actually run by the time the user sees his/her starting location on the map. And I have already put the non-initially viewed Tiles in a Thread to load.

Answer (score 0):

having an endless map is not so difficult to achive, it's mainly difficult to maintain

the trick is that you don't load all tiles at once but only load the tiles that are visible, thus called a viewport.

```
public class ViewPort{
    private Tile[][] visibleTiles;

    public ViewPort(int width, int height, Factory factory){
        //create the Tiles and add them using a proper layout
        ....
    }

    public void setViewLocation(int x, int y){
    for(int dy = 0; dy < getHeight(); dy++){ //getHeight() with height from constructor
        for(int dx = 0; dx < getWidth(); dy++){ //getWidth() with width from constructor 
            visibleTiles[dx][dy] = factory.getTiles(dx+x, dy+y);
        } 
    }
}
```

if you use this design you can jump to any location on your map, you only have to use a proper factory.

The harder problem is creating a good factory:

```
public class Factory{
    public Tile getTile(int x, int y){
        if (x==0 && y==0) return getTile(TileType.Grass);
        ...
        return null;    
    }

    //speeding up using a lookup table, so we only create objects 
    //when we need new one / reUse old ones
    private Map<TileType, Tile> lookUpTable = ...;
    private Tile getTile(TileType type){
        Tile value = lookUpTable.get(type);
        if(value == null){
            value = new Tile(...);
            lookUpTable.put(type, value);
        }
        return value;
}
```

and what looks kind of easy now is very hard to maintain:

```
if (x==0 && y==0) return getTile(TileType.Grass);
if (x==1 && y==0) return getTile(TileType.Grass);
```

this code is neither maintainable nor efficient, you should use switch/case

```
switch(x){
    case 0: 
    switch (y){
        case 0: return getTile(TileType.Grass);
        ...
    }
}
```

is neither maintainable nor readable...

Comment: there would be another issue: using the proper gui elements, instead of using layers you could simple draw onto **one** object and paint these layers directly

Comment: if you want to create a big map using 10.000 x 10.000 tiles you need an editor and you definitely have to break the map into map-pieces (areas)

Comment: there would be another issue: just load the images once and draw them only when you need them, best effort is using imageId for drawing

Comment: I didn't think of just drawing what I need and voiding layers... It seemed like extra work when I made it, but I completely forgot about that once I had the map created and ran into the loading issue. It's a good idea, and I'll try it if I can't set up good tactics for loading specific areas first.

Comment: And as for the editor, I have already created one. I load the map like normal, then modify it with a HUD, and finally, I save it to a .txt file that it will be loaded from. I also may make the editor have a scroll feature of some sort. And the areas already kind of have sections, for example, "Forest" or "Castle." By the way, I already do just load the images once. Only the initial loading of my program is an issue.